# Gtk+ g_signal_connect() and C++ lambda results in "invalid cast" errors

Tags: c++, lambda, callback, gtk

I would like to use lambdas with [`g_signal_connect()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect) from Gtk+. 
 Traditionally works like this to setup a callback function:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <iostream>

void my_callback(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
    std::cout << "test1" << std::endl;
}

void test1()
{
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new(nullptr, G_APPLICATION_NON_UNIQUE);
    void * data = nullptr; // simple example
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(my_callback), data);
}
```

Above test is compiled with `g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0) test.cpp` to get the necessary GTK+-3.0 definitions.

In attempting to convert `my_callback1()` to a lambda, I tried variations of this:

```
void test2()
{
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new(nullptr, G_APPLICATION_NON_UNIQUE);
    void * data = nullptr; // simple example

    // use lambda instead of call to explicit function
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate",
        G_CALLBACK(
            [](GtkApplication *application, gpointer user_data)
            {
                std::cout << "test2" << std::endl;
            }
        ), data);
}
```

The `test2()` code above produces the following compile error:

```
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gclosure.h:70:41: error: invalid cast
from type ‘test2()::<lambda(GtkApplication*, gpointer)>’
to type ‘GCallback {aka void (*)()}’
```

Is there a way to specify a C++ lambda as the callback function?  I don't understand what is needed to fix this "invalid cast".

Comment: Basic first question: are you using a C++11 (or later) capable compiler? Are you telling it to use C++11 or later (it may not do so by default)?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Obviously, he does, otherwise `test2()::<lambda>` would not have been recognised as type?

Comment: @JesperJuhl C++ didn't have lambdas until C++11.  But yes, for this test I'm currently using g++ 7.2.0.

Comment: @Aconcagua it wouldn't have been the first time that someone tried to use a C++111 feature with a C++98 compiler and didn't recognize that as being the error. Given no proof of competence I'm sceptical by default.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Sure, but I'd assume that then we'd have either some kind of warning/error: "lambda not available in pre-C++1 mode" or the lambda syntax simply not being recognised - but as the type is well known, but cannot be casted...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you look at the definition of [`G_CALLBACK`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Closures.html#G-CALLBACK:CAPS), you see that it's merely a cast to a `void (*)()`.  This is Gtk+ employing a form of type erasure on the pointer types it receives, removing the argument list.

The lambda defines a (closure) object type. It's not a function. And while a capture-less lambda does have an implicit conversion operator to a function pointer, that pointer has a signature that matches the lambda's parameter list.

So you may convert the lambda to a `void(*)(GtkApplication*, gpointer)`, but not directly to a `void (*)()` since it's a completely unrelated type.

The workaround is to make the lambda convert into a function pointer type before feeding it to `G_CALLBACK` for the cast. One neat trick that does it, is appending a `+` before the lambda:

```
g_signal_connect(app, "activate",
       G_CALLBACK(
           +[](GtkApplication *application, gpointer user_data)
           {
               std::cout << "test2" << std::endl;
           }
       ), data);
```

Since unary + isn't overloaded for lambdas, the compiler is being helpful and does a conversion to a pointer for us (something unary + may be applied to). After that, the cast in the macro should work.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and the incredibly simple solution.  Never would have thought of this myself.

Comment: Don't know, feeling somewhat uncomfortable with the unary `+`. Certainly quite unlikely that it ever gets defined, but still... Apart from, nice answer.

Comment: @Aconcagua - I don't know about it getting defined, but if the lambda is made convertible to multiple things + may be applied to (VC++ actually does that...), then yeah, this breaks. But the OP is using GTK and it seems like they are on a *nix variant, so this should be fine. Your solution is more robust. I just have a hobby for applying as little modification to the OP as possible.

Comment: @StoryTeller Cannot deny that the brevity has some kind of elegance, too... Obviously, though, this encourages unportable code, some [windows](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php) user might stumble over here and try the same. I don't mind relying on UC, but hinting to (in the answer itself, not the comments only, not all do read these) might possibly be a good idea?

Comment: @Aconcagua - I'm still hopeful VC++ actually listen to reason and don't let that implementation details of theirs slip. The use of `+` is sanctioned by the standard, and every popular compiler besides VC++ respects that. I'm holding on to hope.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is a pointer type mismatch, as the error message clearly tells:

```
invalid cast from type ‘test2()::<lambda(GtkApplication*, gpointer)>’
                                         ^ accepting 2 parameters^
to type ‘GCallback {aka void (*)()}’
                                 ^ no parameter...
```

The more interesting question now would be: Why did the first attempt work then? Well, obviously, the C style cast in the conversion macro acts as `reinterpret_cast` to another function pointer. This is possible for raw function pointers, not so, however, with lambdas...

To get around, the lambda first must be casted to appropriate function pointer; you might try this piece of code for illustration:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    void(*f)(void) = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(void)>
    (
        static_cast<void(*)(int)>([](int n){ std::cout << n; })
    );
    reinterpret_cast<void(*)(...)>(f)(7);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(used C++ cast instead of C style cast here).